# How to Add Label to docker image using build job's parameter which is passed while running job manually

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, label, cicd

I am trying to add a label to docker image during build time. I don't want to add static label like version=2.0.
I have to use build job parameter to add label.
Suppose VERSION is the parameter passed during build time. I want to use it in label as below:
version=${VERSION}
WHAT should I do?

VALUE OF VERSION comes from jenkins job and provided by user while he trigger the build job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ARG instruction ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)). You can see a similar use case to yours in the doc where the Dockerfile is defined as:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG CONT_IMG_VER
ENV CONT_IMG_VER=${CONT_IMG_VER}
RUN echo $CONT_IMG_VER
```

The variable `${CONT_IMG_VER}` is then given during build time:

```
docker build --build-arg CONT_IMG_VER=v2.0.1 .
```